# NotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter not work for certain phone

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val notificationManager:NotificationManager = context.getSystemService(
    Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
) as NotificationManager

notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(
    NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL
)
```

The code is simple, just change the InterruptionFilter, I'
ve already got the DoNotDisturb permission, and it works on emulator.

But when I tested on a real device (OnePlus3) which has the same system of the emulator (Android 7.1.1 API25 with Google services installed), it doesn't work. The code executed, no error, no changes which means it doesn't change the current filter from `INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE` to `INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL`.

What happended and how to fix it?